# Редирект с https на http, после удаления ssl сертификата

Tags: nginx, http, ssl, https, redirect

Раньше на сайте был ssl сертификат, сейчас его убрали
и мне надо сделать редирект со старых адресов с https

Comment: Это невозможно, в этом вся суть https

Comment: Поищите тут : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893839/how-do-i-redirect-https-requests-to-http-in-nginx

Answer (score 1):

для того, чтобы передать http-клиенту ответ (неважно, 301-й или любой иной), он должен установить https-соединение с вашим сервером. а для установки соединения необходимо предоставить клиенту действующий сертификат.

поэтому то, что вам требуется, с http-клиентами, следующими стандартам, осуществить невозможно.