# Переадресация с https на http для поддоменов

Tags: nginx

Пытаюсь переадресовать поддомены https на http. Конфиг nginx:

```
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name  *.domain.com;
    return 301 http://$host$request_uri;
}
```

При переходе на https://subdomain.domain.com/ переадресация не работает. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как корректно сделать переадресацию? Так же нужна переадресация `http://www.subdomain.domain.com -> http://subdomain.domain.com` и `https://www.subdomain.domain.com -> http://subdomain.domain.com`. Спасибо! `nginx/1.6.2`

Comment: DNS настроен? Сертификат есть?

Comment: Вообще-то уже давно модно настраивать редирект в другую сторону. Особенно в свете того, что браузеры всё сильнее закручивают гайки в сторону https

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/769404/178576

Comment: Есть сертификат только на домен, на поддомены - не распространяется, поэтому редирект с https на http.

Comment: С редиректом https -> http понятно (это не возможно сделать), а как быть с `http://www.subdomain.domain.com -> http://subdomain.domain.com`?

Comment: А это уже другой вопрос которого нет в изначальной теме

Answer (score 0):

Нужно отойти от логики определения всех возможных неверных вариантов. Гораздо проще определить правильный сервер, а всё остальное просто направить на него:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  example.com;
    ...
}
server {
    listen       80 default_server; 
    server_name  _;
    return       301 http://example.com$request_uri;
}
```

Источник: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/converting_rewrite_rules.html