# Редирект поддоменов с https на http, nginx - возможно?

Tags: nginx, редирект, поддомены

Добрый день!
Есть VPS nginx+apache. Где-то вычитал, что сделать редирект с https на http нельзя, если нет ssl сертификата на поддомены. Возможно все-таки есть возможность сделать редирект в nginx или .htaccess?
А то основной домен на https и бывает что пытаются заходить на поддомены также (а на них нет ssl).

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/351252/

Comment: Без сертификата нельзя

Comment: дубликат: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/769320/178576

Comment: Спасибо всё понял, можно закрывать )))

Answer (score 1):

Без сертификата действительно нельзя!
Можно использовать wildcart сертификат от Let's Encrypt на поддомены и не париться. Они оказывается сделали недавно такую возможность.