# Не получается сделать редирект с https на http в nginx

Tags: nginx, ssl

Всем привет. Купил домен, который ранее принадлежал другому человеку. От старого домена в индексе google присутствуют страницы с https.
Сайт, который  хочу залить на этот домен работает на http, поэтому мне нужно сделать редирект при заходе на страницу с https на http. Перерыл интернет, перепробовал кучу вариантов - не работает.

Вот мой конфиг nginx:

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    access_log off;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    client_max_body_size 10M;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;


server {
    listen       myip:80;
    server_name .mysite12.com;

    location / {
        root   /home/site12;
        index  index.php;
if ($scheme = https) {
    return 301 http://$host$request_uri;
}
        if (!-e $request_filename) {
               rewrite ^ /index.php last;
               break;
        }
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        root           /home/site12;
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass   unix:/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }
}


}
```

Добавил

```
if ($scheme = https) {
    return 301 http://$host$request_uri;
}
```

как мне кажется самый логичный вариант, но не работает...
Помогите сделать редирект с http на https

Comment: Что бы сделать редирект вам всё равно нужен валидный сертификат. А если есть сертификат, то логичнее сделать сайт на https.

Comment: Ну и в любом случае, надо бы слушать 443 порт, иначе запросы по https просто не доходят до сервера

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Редирект с https на http, после удаления ssl сертификата](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/769320/%d0%a0%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82-%d1%81-https-%d0%bd%d0%b0-http-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-ssl-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Без валидного сертификата сделать редирект никак не получится.
Редирект сработает только после установки https соединения.

LetsEncrypt никто ещё не отменял.